# How to get count of Dates that fall in between to Date columns in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following Data,

```
logType log_create_date error_date
A   2019-01-01  2019-01-02
A   2019-02-04  2019-02-03
A   2019-03-10  2019-03-07
A   2019-04-13  2019-04-08
B   2019-05-17  2019-05-10
B   2019-06-20  2019-06-11
B   2019-07-24  2019-07-13
B   2019-08-27  2019-08-14
```

Which I have managed to turn in to below using,

```
val window = Window.orderBy("logType","log_crate_date")
val lagCol = lag(col("log_crate_date"), 1).over(window)
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM test")
.withColumn("log_create_date_previous", lagCol)
.select("logType","log_create_date_previous","log_create_date","error_date")

    logType log_create_date_previous    log_create_date error_date
    A   null    2019-01-01  2019-01-02
    A   2019-01-01  2019-02-04  2019-02-03
    A   2019-02-04  2019-03-10  2019-03-07
    A   2019-03-10  2019-04-13  2019-04-08
    B   2019-04-13  2019-05-17  2019-05-10
    B   2019-05-17  2019-06-20  2019-06-11
    B   2019-06-20  2019-07-24  2019-07-13
    B   2019-07-24  2019-08-27  2019-08-14
    B   2019-08-27  2019-08-27  null
```

Now I want to count for each $logType, and in b/w a distinct log_create_date_previous & log_create_date how many error_date Counts has happened by counting how many error_date's falls under log_create_date_previous & log_create_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculate how many records has "error_date" between "log_create_date_previous" and "log_create_date" for each type, "between" function can be used:

```
  .withColumn("error_in_between", $"error_date".between($"log_create_date_previous", $"log_create_date"))
  .groupBy("logType").agg(sum(when($"error_in_between", 1).otherwise(0)).alias("error_count"))
```

For provided dataset, result is:

```
+-------+-----------+
|logType|error_count|
+-------+-----------+
|A      |3          |
|B      |4          |
+-------+-----------+
```